# Creating Gadgets fails

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I've defined a data source in cep console, moved over to the cep analytics dashboard and tried to create a new gadget. This fails with an error. No datasources available. Looking at the source code for creating gadgets there is a dependency to an analytics service stub that's not part of the default install. I switched over to using DAS and got the same error. Anyone got any pointers to getting this to work?

Comment: Can you mentioned the DAS version and also paste the error log. Also can you make sure the  datasource connection is successful by clicking the "Test connection" button?. I hope you have copied the relevant datasource driver jar to <DAS_HOME>/repository/components/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually data source of the gadget is not data sources for databases. Data source for the gadgets are data streams in CEP and DAS.

There are two types of gadgets.

**1. Real time processing gadgets** - These gadgets will plot data in real time as immediately data received for the stream. In order to create these, you need to create a UI publisher for the stream [1]. Then the stream will be displayed as a data source in dashboard gadget creation. Please refer CEP documentation on how to create a real time gadget [2].

**2. Batch processing gadgets** - These gadgets will load data from analytics event tables and plot. In WSO2 DAS if you create a stream and persist it to event table [3], those will streams will be shown as data sources in analytic dashboard. Please refer DAS documentation on how to create a gadget [4]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/UI+Event+Publisher

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Creating+Gadgets

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Understanding+Event+Streams+and+Event+Tables

[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Adding+Gadgets+to+a+Dashboard